# export variables in truffle console

Tags: truffle, javascript

I learned from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54556720/cannot-exec-simple-javascript-file-into-truffle that external scripts must be in the module.exports pattern.

I wrote console.js with the following code and I wish to export variable `j`.

```js
module.exports = function(callback) {
    console.log("test");
    j=1;
}
```

```
truffle(development)> exec console.js
Using network 'development'.

test
truffle(development)> j
evalmachine.<anonymous>:0
j
^

Uncaught ReferenceError: j is not defined
```

What's the correct syntax to export a variable? I can't find it on https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/writing-external-scripts . Can someone give guidance?